# How to look for a word in a sentence which is also a part of a big word in the same string?

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching

I have a string like this

```
String test = "[Short: 1234, Long: 3456, At_Long: 1234, Get_Long: 56788]"
```

I need to make sure that my string has the word **Long**. Sometimes, the order of the contents in the string is changed. For instance

```
String test = "[Long: 1234, Short: 3456, At_Long: 1234, Get_Long: 56788]"
```

So, when I look for

```
test.contains(" Long:")
```

I get nothing because the order occasionally changes. If I remove the leading space, it considers At_Long, Get_long as well. How do I make the system just look for the word Long: ?

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: The language is Java

Comment: Try `test.matches("(?s).*\\bLong\\b.*")` or `(" " + test).contains(" Long:")`

Comment: `test.contains(" Long:") || test.contains("[Long:")`

Comment: Thanks :) Can you explain me the regex you have written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String#matches` with `(?s).*\\bLong:.*` regex:

```
String test = "[Long: 1234, Short: 3456, At_Long: 1234, Get_Long: 56788]";
System.out.println(test.matches("(?s).*\\bLong:.*"));
```

See the [regex demo](http://ideone.com/2XwOj1)

**Explanation**:

- `(?s)` - enables DOTALL mode (the `.` starts matching newlines, too)
- `.*` - matches any 0+ characters
- `\\bLong:` - matches a whole word `Long:` (`\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html))
- `.*` - matches any 0+ characters (necessary since `matches` requires a full string match).

*Note*: If you do not care about the `:` after `Long`, you can use `.matches("(?s).*\\bLong\\b.*")` so that the `Long` could be matched as a whole word.

Comment: And here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tI8bZ1/1). There is a more "technical" explanation on the right.